# Question on time speed and distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B, who are separated by a distance 90 m, are approaching towards each other. The initial speed of A is 5 m/s and that of B is 10 m/s. If A increases his speed by 5 m/s every second, when will they meet each other?

Comment: Do you think A is continuously accelerating at 5 m/s^2 or that A travels at 5 m/s for the first second, then instantly acclerates and travels at 10 m/s for the second second and so on?  I find the wording ambiguous.

Comment: A is continuously accelerating @RossMillikan I now know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let the distance $d$ between the two be expressed a a function of time $t$. Then you have that the rate of change of the distance is 
$$d'(t)=-5-10-5t$$
$$d'(t)=-15-5t$$
The two will meet when $d(t)=0$. Can you integrate, find the constant that is added when you integrate, and then find when $d(t)=0$?

FULL ANSWER:
Integrate both sides to get
$$d(t)=-15t-\frac{5}{2}t^2+C$$
And since the starting distance is $90$, then $C=90$, so
$$d(t)=-15t-\frac{5}{2}t^2+90$$
And you must find when this is zero:
$$-\frac{5}{2}t^2-15t+90=0$$
$$\frac{5}{2}t^2+15t-90=0$$
This can be solved like a quadratic:
$$t^2+6t-36=0$$
Can you use the quadratic formula to solve this?

Comment: Is there any easier way to do this

Comment: ...perhaps, but I don't think it will get much easier than this. Should I add a little bit to my hint?

Comment: In 1 second A will cover 5m, then in 2 seconds it will cover 15 m....Am I right? @Frpzzd

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then why my answer is not right @Frpzzd

Comment: Hold on. I'll write you a complete answer.

Comment: @Frpzzd:  your solution assumes constant acceleration, but your second comment accepts stepped velocity on the part of A.  With constant acceleration A covers 7.5m in one second and 20m in the first two seconds. I find the question ambiguous.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hey, I have understood this one. Can you please help me out with another question that I have posted?

Answer (score -2):

$A$ & $B$ are $90$ m distance apart.

Their relative speed is $(10+5)$ m/sec

Say, after $t$ second, they meet each other at a distance $x$ from the point from where $A$ starts.

We can say that both of them in combination have covered $90$ m distance within $t$ secs at a speed of $15$ m/s

so $t = \frac{90}{15} = 6$ secs

Comment: I think you missed the fact that A's speed is increasing.